# BeautifulSoup scrape tags with same class name

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to BeautifulSoup. I'm using Python and bs to do some web scraping and I have two paragraphs with the same class name. The HTML is as follows:

`<p class='metadata'>Wed 1 Jan 2020 00:01 GMT</p><p class='metadata'>Category: <span>UK-News</span></p>`

I'm trying to get just the category name that's within the span tags (UK-News). I'm using a loop as I'm scraping multiple articles. Here's some of the things I've tried:

```
articles = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'article'})

for item in articles:
    #category = item.find('span') - prints out the same date 
    #category = item.find('p', {'class' : 'metadata'}).text - prints every span tag in html
    #category = item.find('p', {'class' : 'metadata'}) - prints only the dates
    category = soup.select_one('span').get_text #prints out the same category name
    print(category)
```

It's probably a small fix, but it's really wrecking my head as I feel like I tried everything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does `articles` come from and what does it look like? or is it just a list of URLs?

Comment: try using a CSS selector, something like `soup.select('p.metadata > span')`.

Comment: @Boris oops, forgot to include that. will update the code. each article has it's own div, so i'm searching through the tags within each article div. i tried the css selector and it's working but prints out each category name 51 times (there's 51 articles). li'll ook more into this though, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're searching in `soup` inside the loop. Change it to `item.select_one`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<article>
<p class='metadata'>Wed 1 Jan 2020 00:01 GMT</p>
<p class='metadata'>Category: <span>UK-News</span></p>
</article>

<article>
<p class='metadata'>Wed 2 Jan 2020 00:01 GMT</p>
<p class='metadata'>Category: <span>World-News</span></p>
</article>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

articles = soup.find_all("article")
for item in articles:
    category = item.select_one("p.metadata span").text  # <-- use item.select
    print(category)
```

Prints:

```
UK-News
World-News
```